# React.js filter and collecting data from local JSON file

Tags: reactjs

This question regards collecting JSON-data from a local file and doing multiple state updates.

Im using `import database from './db.json'` to collect JSON-data in my parent component (app.js) is this a proper way to import local data?

**db.json**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "key": 1,
            "name": "Item 1",
        },
        {
            "key": 2,
            "name": "Item 2",
        },
        ...
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import db from './db.json';

export default class App extends Component {
    ...
}
```

After import, database get set as a state

```
    this.state = {
        database: db,
        term: '',
    };
```

Example of a method

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({term: e.target.value})
};
```

State and methods transfers as props to child components (stateless)

```
<Component onChange={this.onChange} stateOfDb={this.state.database} />
```

All my methods are placed in App.js and being passed down to stateless components, is this a good practice?

What if I want to create a search function and be able to filter thru each item in the database, how could a example of this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always filter stuff directly on render-time.

Ex:

```
updateSearch(ev){
    this.setState({searchString: ev.target.value});
}
render(){
  const filterData = this.state.searchString ? this.state.database.filter(row => row.someProperty.indexOf(this.state.searchString) > -1) : this.state.database;

  <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={(ev) => this.updateSearch(ev)} />
    <ChildComponentToRenderData data={filteredData} />
  </div>
}
```

You dont even have to put the database in state, since it is in fact just held in memory after the import. So in fact, instead of filtering using this.state.database, you can actually just do db.filter. Probably also nice to check if the searchString is actually set when filtering.

Comment: .filter expects a bool, so instead of returning indexof, you can just return >, < >= or whatever operator you want